# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'temporary_address' cannot be null error in nullable field

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I set the default value for a field on migration but it still gives an error when I left form field `temporary_address` empty
[image: problem field]

Is no-value and null is same in laravel? or something else.

> my php version: 7.2.15
>
> my mysql version: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25
>
> My laravel version: 5.7.27

Comment: Please include the code and errors as text. Images are difficult to view, search for, and in this case they cut off key information

Comment: please also attach your insertion code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
$client->temporary_address = $request->get('temporary_address');
```

please change this to

```php
if(!empty($request->temporary_address)){
   $client->temporary_address = $request->get('temporary_address');
}
```

Comment: then use !empty($request->temporary_address)

Comment: @RamBhandari if this answers your question mark it as the accepted answer so this question would stop popping up in the "unanswered questions" feed.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you decide to **not** using nullable() on the temporary address, while the other already using nullable

why you got an error ?

Because your temporary_address not accepting null value, and you set default value as an empty string, therefore you got an error like in your post, the solution change the default value to some value, not an empty string or easily make it nullable the best solution.

change this code

```
$table->string('temporary_address')->default("");
```

since you already run migration to update it, you need to write it down like this

```
$table->string('temporary_address')->nullable()->change();
```

therefore you can left your temporary address empty

Comment: Yes, I used nullable first but when I search data my search query doesn't work when I search for a blank location where my expected result is all address if not entered any address.

Comment: i don't understand what's the correlation between this problem with search query case,
you just need to check if it's null then query to all address,  if its has an address, it took param query as the address input

Comment: @RamBhandari the problem of yours, you're inserting default an empty string, while your temporary_address not accepting null value thats why you get an error , therefore you just need to change the temporary_address as nullable

Comment: Oh yes, that can also be a solution another solution can be checking if $request is null or not and if it is null then don't do anything else store the value from $request